# Iterating over a DataFrame in ReportLab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, reportlab

I want to iterate over the DataFrame (df) to produce a PDF for each hospital ('A' and 'B'). I tried many ways, but have not been successful unless I make the name a random number with np.random.rand(1), but that still had issues. Update: 
I want the name of the .pdf to be the hospital name per iteration. If I try to add the hospital name, it results in an error:

When I set:

```
pdf_file_name = str(np.random.rand(1))+'.pdf'
```

The result is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '0    A\nName: Hospital, dtype: object.pdf'
```

So I need go figure out how to:
1. Pass the hospital name in to the file name and
2. Iterate over hospital names to produce one PDF per hospital.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait
from reportlab.platypus import Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hospital':['A','B']})
#This is here to just produce one report that "works" while working on the code.
df = df[(df.Hospital == 'A')]

hospital = df['Hospital']
def import_data(df):
    import numpy as np
    hospital = df['Hospital']
    pdf_file_name = str(np.random.rand(1))+'.pdf'
    generate_report(hospital, pdf_file_name)

def generate_report(hospital, pdf_file_name):
    c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_file_name, pagesize=portrait(letter))
    c.setFont('Helvetica', 48, leading=None)
    c.drawCentredString(415, 500, 'Report')
    c.setFont('Helvetica', 24, leading=None)
    c.drawCentredString(415, 450, 'This Report is For:')
    c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 34, leading=None)
    c.drawCentredString(415, 395, str(hospital))
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
import_data(df)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, please see updated code.

Comment: Updated again. Now, I believe it is the minimal code or close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do something like

```
def import_data(df):
    for hospital, hosp_df in df.groupby("Hospital"):
        pdf_file_name = hospital + '.pdf'
        generate_report(hospital, pdf_file_name)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hospital':['A','B'], 'Other': [1,2]})
import_data(df)
```

This produces two files for me, one called `A.pdf` and the second called `B.pdf`, each of which say "Report / This Report is For: / A" (or B).

At the moment we're not doing anything with `hosp_df`, which looks like

```
A
  Hospital  Other
0        A      1
```

and

```
B
  Hospital  Other
1        B      2
```

but you can pass `hosp_df` into `generate_report` as well and do anything you want with that hospital-specific data.